# Extension Development which should include Payment Gateway Magento

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway

I'm Creating an extension that showcases products on the left hand side and when the product is selected it is added as an order on the right hand side without going to another page, once the user is satisfied with the order he can click on place order which will enable payment gateway in the same page right below the order form. Could someone help me understand how i can extract the payment gateway module used in the normal flow of magento and insert it within my module. The user should see the payment method that he can select during the order process within the same page.

Comment: Are you asking how to get list of active payment methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you get all active payment methods.

```
$payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();
```

`$payments` is array type variable. You can see name method like:

```
foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel) 
{
    $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
    echo "Code: " . $payMethods[$paymentCode] ", Title: " . $paymentTitle . "<br /";

}
```

Once you get module, you can render each of methods so that user can select one.

Comment: Thank you for providing the code. Could you please explain me how do i render each method so that the user can select the payment method and it can be used for the checkout process. Im new to extension development. Thanks in advance